# Tensorflow estimator unknown Input/output error on Azure Databricks

Tags: python-3.x, azure, tensorflow, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to run the official BERT pretraining scripts based on this tutorial https://towardsdatascience.com/pre-training-bert-from-scratch-with-cloud-tpu-6e2f71028379 with the main exception that I am trying to use Azure Databricks. When I try to run the tensorflow estimator to train the net it starts to run ok, saving the first iteration of the model. However when it tries to save the second itteration I get an Input/output error which looks like its caused by trying to rename a temporary file. Does anybody know a resolution to this problem?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3548884146162520> in <module>()
----> 1 estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=TRAIN_STEPS)

/databricks/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py in train(self, input_fn, hooks, steps, max_steps, saving_listeners)
   2874     finally:
   2875       rendezvous.record_done('training_loop')
-> 2876       rendezvous.raise_errors()
   2877 
   2878   def evaluate(self,

/databricks/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/error_handling.py in raise_errors(self, timeout_sec)
    129       else:
    130         logging.warn('Reraising captured error')
--> 131         six.reraise(typ, value, traceback)
    132 
    133     for k, (typ, value, traceback) in kept_errors:

/databricks/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    691             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    692                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 693             raise value
    694         finally:
    695             value = None

/databricks/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py in train(self, input_fn, hooks, steps, max_steps, saving_listeners)
   2869           steps=steps,
   2870           max_steps=max_steps,
-> 2871           saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
   2872     except Exception:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
   2873       rendezvous.record_error('training_loop', sys.exc_info())

/databricks/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py in train(self, input_fn, hooks, steps, max_steps, saving_listeners)
    365 
    366       saving_listeners = _check_listeners_type(saving_listeners)
--> 367       loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
    368       logging.info('Loss for final step: %s.', loss)
    369       return self

/databricks/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py in _train_model(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1156       return self._train_model_distributed(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1157     else:
-> 1158       return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1159 
   1160   def _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners):

/databricks/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py in _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
   1190       return self._train_with_estimator_spec(estimator_spec, worker_hooks,
   1191                                              hooks, global_step_tensor,
-> 1192                                              saving_listeners)
   1193 
   1194   def _train_model_distributed(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners):

/databricks/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py in _train_with_estimator_spec(self, estimator_spec, worker_hooks, hooks, global_step_tensor, saving_listeners)
   1482       any_step_done = False
   1483       while not mon_sess.should_stop():
-> 1484         _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
   1485         any_step_done = True
   1486     if not any_step_done:

/databricks/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    752         feed_dict=feed_dict,
    753         options=options,
--> 754         run_metadata=run_metadata)
    755 
    756   def run_step_fn(self, step_fn):

/databricks/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1250             feed_dict=feed_dict,
   1251             options=options,
-> 1252             run_metadata=run_metadata)
   1253       except _PREEMPTION_ERRORS as e:
   1254         logging.info(

/databricks/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py in run(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1351         raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
   1352       else:
-> 1353         raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
   1354 
   1355 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    691             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    692                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 693             raise value
    694         finally:
    695             value = None

/databricks/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py in run(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1336   def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
   1337     try:
-> 1338       return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
   1339     except _PREEMPTION_ERRORS:
   1340       raise

/databricks/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1417               results=outputs[hook] if hook in outputs else None,
   1418               options=options,
-> 1419               run_metadata=run_metadata))
   1420     self._should_stop = self._should_stop or run_context.stop_requested
   1421 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py in after_run(self, run_context, run_values)
    592       if self._timer.should_trigger_for_step(global_step):
    593         self._timer.update_last_triggered_step(global_step)
--> 594         if self._save(run_context.session, global_step):
    595           run_context.request_stop()
    596 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py in _save(self, session, step)
    609       l.before_save(session, step)
    610 
--> 611     self._get_saver().save(session, self._save_path, global_step=step)
    612     self._summary_writer.add_session_log(
    613         SessionLog(

/databricks/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py in save(self, sess, save_path, global_step, latest_filename, meta_graph_suffix, write_meta_graph, write_state, strip_default_attrs, save_debug_info)
   1181               all_model_checkpoint_paths=self.last_checkpoints,
   1182               latest_filename=latest_filename,
-> 1183               save_relative_paths=self._save_relative_paths)
   1184           self._MaybeDeleteOldCheckpoints(meta_graph_suffix=meta_graph_suffix)
   1185       except (errors.FailedPreconditionError, errors.NotFoundError) as exc:

/databricks/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpoint_management.py in update_checkpoint_state_internal(save_dir, model_checkpoint_path, all_model_checkpoint_paths, latest_filename, save_relative_paths, all_model_checkpoint_timestamps, last_preserved_timestamp)
    240   # file.
    241   file_io.atomic_write_string_to_file(coord_checkpoint_filename,
--> 242                                       text_format.MessageToString(ckpt))
    243 
    244 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py in atomic_write_string_to_file(filename, contents, overwrite)
    538   write_string_to_file(temp_pathname, contents)
    539   try:
--> 540     rename(temp_pathname, filename, overwrite)
    541   except errors.OpError:
    542     delete_file(temp_pathname)

/databricks/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py in rename(oldname, newname, overwrite)
    500     errors.OpError: If the operation fails.
    501   """
--> 502   rename_v2(oldname, newname, overwrite)
    503 
    504 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py in rename_v2(src, dst, overwrite)
    517   """
    518   pywrap_tensorflow.RenameFile(
--> 519       compat.as_bytes(src), compat.as_bytes(dst), overwrite)
    520 
    521 

UnknownError: /dbfs/tmp/model/checkpoint.tmp2feb8d7a932249e7ba1a11f96d3cb334; Input/output error
```